# How should I use the "Move to Resource" feature of Resharper

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a MessageBox in C# like so:

```
MessageBox.Show("Message Here", "Title Here", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Under my Message and Title I have the option in ReSharper to `Move to Resource` and it wants to move these values to the Resources.resx file and then just refer to them in my MessageBox.

Is this overkill, not what this feature is really for or a good idea?

Thanks

Comment: If you'd like to make your application localizable, yes, it's a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is not overkill. Even if you are 100% certain (can you really be?) that you never need to provide your application in a different language, it makes the code much more readable, if it is not "littered" with strings/messages.

Personally, I found out that I started writing much better (error) messages, once I moved all of them to resources. Before that I was trying too hard to make them "look nice" in the code, than to provide a really meaningful message.

Of course, there are also drawbacks. While navigation usually doesn't suffer (ReSharper's "Go To Definition" works equally well with string resources), you don't get checking of `string.Format` parameters. Again, for me that was worth the price of having (arguably cleaner code and better messages). YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

If you just use one language (i.e. English) now and in the future you can ignore ReSharper's internationalization features. But if it can happen that you will support other languages you should move all strings (that appear in user interface) to the Resources.

Answer (score 0):

The `move to resource` feature was introduced to aid in internationalization. When R# detects a string which can be localized, it offers to move it to a resource file for you. The benefit of this is that the strings in the .resx can be changed to different languages without having to recompile any code.

See the ReSharper documentation on this [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html).